# How can I access EPST on the Motorola Droid 1 (Verizon)?

Tags: settings, motorola-droid, verizon

I've tried "##778#", "##778 send", and "##778# send" but every time it dials the number giving me a "Welcome to Verizon..." message instead of opening the provisioning screen (except for option 1 which does nothing).

Comment: what is EPST?  What are you trying to do?

Comment: I'm not sure exactly EPST stands for but it's a way to enter the carrier settings on your phone through the keypad.  I'm trying to edit my Network Access Identifier to enable WAP.  From what I've read this is done by changing your NAI from my10digit#@dun.vzw3g.com to my10digit#@vzw3g.com.  This calls for using programming codes (##...), which you use for other things as well like reprogramming your voicemail providers... anyway instead of opening provisioning menu it just tries to make a phone call.

Comment: My phone just clears the entered code on 2.2/custom ROM, but it worked on 2.1/stock.

Comment: So it must be a 2.2 thing.  I haven't been able to get it to work on Stock 2.2 or on CM 6.1.

Answer (score 1):

This may not be what you're looking for (I can't find any options for EPST in this menu) but give **##7764726** a try.  The password is 000000 (six zeros) and it should bring up a menu with 9 different options.  Maybe what you want is in there somewhere.

I know that using option 4 and setting EVRC-B will make your call quality better.  Normally it's set to EVRC.

Comment: Thanks but my droid isn't activated anymore. just curious, what other options did it give you?

Comment: Give me a few minutes and I'll post a screenshot or two.  And since I've got your attention, can you give me more detail on what you were trying to accomplish?  Near as I can tell enabling WAP would be redundant if you have a data plan on your phone, but I may be misinterpreting the (sparse) information I've found.

Comment: @Matt - https://dl-web.dropbox.com/get/Public/Droid%20Screenshots/2011-03-24/2011-03-24_10.31.36.png?w=8f2a6eff  The last option is just "09 Data Call Settings"